# Translate text in Magento, but in an Admin Observer

Tags: magento, translation

I need to translate a string based on the language of the shop where the customer bought.
What I need is to send an email when I approve a review in Admin area.
But I have multi-shop and every store has its own language settings.

I tried with 
$comment = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Review our shop');
This is being sent in english, doesn't matter the language of the store where the user sent the review.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have translation of this phrase in file: /app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way
I had to catch storeId from the observer event, then bget store locale, then translate the text to the store locale where the event was launched.